# Excel: Return Information (Line items) based on Categories

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am looking for some help to find out if below is possible or not. If possible how should I tackle this..

I would like to made an order form which searches a customers sales history from a pivot table and will determine what categories of product does the customer purchase. For example if the customer purchases items from Category A & Category C than the order form would show these products and not Category B Products.

I have attached a photo example of what I am trying to explain.
[image: Example]

Comment: You mean to say while book the order Excel must check Customer's past purchased history and Show all purchased items along with category ? Any further !!

Comment: I want to show all the items in the category that the customer participated in. So even if they purchase on line item from two different categories, I want to list out all items in both of those categories.

Comment: This is way more complex than you can achieve with a few formulas in a worksheet.  You want to invest in a serious database instead of Excel, and sprinkle some Artificial Intelligence on top. Especially with your data layout in separate columns, this will be impossible to do with Excel, unless you throw a lot of custom VBA code at it. Too big a project for a single question in this site.

Comment: How did the customer enter A,B,C?

Comment: @BrookeBeekhuyzen, my experience says that you Database need few crucial fields to be added like Tran. ID, Customer's Name, Date. This exercise is like you want to Query Customers History. You many try Power Query or MS-Access Query also !!

Comment: I have a complete database which includes all of this information the example data is not my actual data. I was only trying to show what I was hoping to achieve. I will be using pivot tables with the customer as a slicer to filter sales history (As it will look at a previous year the data wont be changing). I was more looking for if I had a list of items by category and a person purchased within 2 different categories than how can I transpose those categories only. The Goal was to create a more custom order form by customer based off what categories they had previously participated in.